# Which method is appropriate to measure correlation when data are not linear or monotonic?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, spearman-rho

I have 2 datasets. Now, I want to check the correlation between these 2 datasets. I have plotted datasets in a scatter plot and plotting shows that they do not follow linear or monotonic relationships.

They are showing something like a cluster (or straight) relationship e.g.: while y is increasing but x is not increasing so much.

I know, we can use `Pearson` for the linear relationship data while `Spearman` for the monotonic relationship data.

Now, in my cases which method should I use to calculate the correlation?

Comment: It becomes necessary to be clear about what you mean by *correlation* in this situation. What's a case with very high "correlation"? With very low "correlation"? Does it make sense for your "correlation" to be negative? etc etc

Comment: In addition to Glen's apt comment, I don't know whether correlation applies here. You suggest your data looks like a cluster, but clusters can take many shapes. All this description tells me is that the persistent homology is probably just a single zero-dimensional hole.

Comment: See: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/_images/sphx_glr_plot_cluster_comparison_001.png

Comment: Well, using Pearson I am getting moderate to negative correlation

Comment: We need more information about your data (can you post an image) and what it is that you trying to learn from that data.